# Unable to install winehq-devel

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, package-management, wine, dependencies

I used the official install guide:

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Unfortunately, at the last step, I got the following error:

```
~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

**Terminal output ->**

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies. 
winehq-devel : depends on: wine-devel (=4.19~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to uninstall all wine packages one by one before I re-installed it, now I m stuck with the wine-devel package, I cant delete for some reason.

Any ideas what could fix my problem?

(Chose the development-branch (winehq-devel) instead stable-branch for I wanted to have the latest version 4.19 -> reason for trying to update to 4.19 was the announcement of: More stateblock support in WineD3D.)

Comment: Copy/pastes from terminal should be in code-blocks "{}" (line-breaks are missing in your italics-highlighted paste).

Comment: ok, seems to be a duplicate but when I go ```dpkg --get-selections | grep hold``` there is nothing. An empty list.

Comment: Also tried the linked "How do I resolve unmet dependencies", but after all those commands I still got the output above.